# choosing the sql statement which use less loading time

Tags: mysql

i have 2 sql statements which produce the same result, but wondering which one to choose?

lets say 1 have 3 tables:

1. supplier
2. supplier_status
3. supplier_contact

statement 1)

```
SELECT a.*, b.status_name
  (SELECT c.name FROM  contact c 
   WHERE c.supplier_id = a.supplier_id 
   ORDER BY c.contact_id DESC limit 1) AS contact_name
FROM supplier a LEFT JOIN supplier_status b 
ON a.status_id = b.status_id
```

statement 2)

```
SELECT a.*, b.status_name, c.name AS contact_name 
FROM supplier a LEFT JOIN supplier_status b 
ON a.status_id = b.status_id 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT name, supplier_id 
   FROM contact  
   ORDER BY contact_id DESC
) c ON a.supplier_id = c.supplier_id
GROUP BY a.supplier_id
```

Comment: Well it depends on what you want your code to look like. You want our opinions?

Comment: Maybe it is just me, but I think an explanation of what you are trying to accomplish will help with good answers.

Comment: Prepend your queries with `EXPLAIN ` run them, check the results against the [documentation of the `EXPLAIN` output](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html)

Comment: I'm sure they can be rewritten without inner queries and maybe even without `GROUP BY`. That could make them faster and easier to understand.

Comment: Your derived table in your second statement is unnecessary. There is no good reason to sort your derived table statement before joining unless you want to waste perfectly good CPU cycles. Removing the derived table and just joining in `Contact` will also help your DB take advantage of any indexing on the `contact` table that is lost when it's stuck in a subquery like that. After that change, your second query would be superior to the first in both I/O, CPU usage, and readability.

Comment: @RyanNaddy It's not just you.

Comment: I'd go with statement 3.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT a.*, b.status_name, c.name AS contact_name
FROM supplier a
  LEFT JOIN supplier_status b ON a.status_id = b.status_id
  LEFT JOIN contact c ON a.supplier_id = c.supplier_id
  LEFT JOIN contact d ON c.supplier_id = d.supplier_id AND c.contact_id < d.contact_id
WHERE d.contact_id IS NULL
```

It's possible that it doesn't produce the same result as yours (I didn't test it) but if it does then all you have to do is to make sure the fields that appear in the `JOIN` conditions are indexed (they probably are `FK`s, so they already are).